# Open and save changes with bash

Tags: linux, bash, console

I'm writing a `bash` script that does is find all `.html` extension files in a directory and remove all tags `<p> </ p>` that are inside `<TXT_accesp> </TXT_accesp>` tag.

So far I have the following code and sample output (via console) works correctly:

```
for i in $(find /home -name *.html); do sed -e '/<TXT_accesp>/,/<\/TXT_accesp>/ s/<p>\(.*\)<\/p>$/\1/g' $i; done
```

The problem is that changes need to be saved in each `.html` file that is modified, because as I said before, when I run make changes but only through the console but not saved in the file.

From already thank you very much to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the for loop, you can use `-exec` option of `find` command do to the substitution.

```
find /home -type f -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '/<TXT_accesp>/,/<\/TXT_accesp>/ s/<p>\(.*\)<\/p>$/\1/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the `sed` man pages.  There's an `-i` flag, which means edit "in-place" (it modifies the file instead of sending the output to the terminal).